# Implement a minimal logger in Golang

Tags: logging, go

I've created a minimal logger in Golang. 
I tried to keep it as simple as possible but two problems arise:

- Message string is shown as array wrapped in brackets []
- filename using `log.Lshortfile` flag is always shown as `logger.go`

[image: CMD]

Here's my code:

```
package logger

import (
    "log"
    "os"
)

var (
    dlog = log.New(os.Stdout, "\x1B[36mDEBUG: \x1B[0m", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    wlog = log.New(os.Stdout, "\x1B[35mWARN: \x1B[0m", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    ilog = log.New(os.Stdout, "\x1B[32mINFO: \x1B[0m", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
    elog = log.New(os.Stderr, "\x1B[31mERROR: \x1B[0m", log.Ldate|log.Ltime|log.Lshortfile)
)

// Debug Log
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
     dlog.Println(a)
}

// Warn log
func Warn(a ...interface{}) {
    wlog.Println(a)
}

// Info Log
func Info(a ...interface{}) {
    ilog.Println(a)
}

// Error Log
func Error(a ...interface{}) {
    elog.Println(a)
}
```

I use them  like this: `logger.Debug("Hello") or logger.Info("There")`

How do I implement this correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Println](https://godoc.org/log#Println) is passed a single parameter, a slice of interface{}, and prints it using slice notation.  To fix this, pass the variadic parameters to your functions as variadic arguments to the called functions.

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
     dlog.Println(a...) // <-- note ... here
}
```

[Here's the doc on variadic args](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters).

Call [Output](https://godoc.org/log#Logger.Output) to workaround the file name issue.

```
func Debug(a ...interface{}) {
     dlog.Output(2, fmt.Sprintln(a...))
}
```